# Replace all spaces in French number

Tags: javascript

I have a Number in French: `a='20 000 000'`. I want to to add 1 to this number and put again it in French: a='20 000 001'`

I am using in JavaScript

```
a=Intl.NumberFormat('fr-FR').format(parseInt(document.getElementById('lblndescargas').innerText.replaceAll('&nbsp;',''))+1)
```

The first time it pass through it it gives 20 000 001. But the second time it gives 21. It seems like the space is not valid as separator.

Why? One year later I make the same question.

And replaceAll( /&nbsp;|\s/g, '' ) doesn't work. It is strange.

Now the number is

```
1 136
```

Internally it is

```
1&nbsp;136
```

I do

```
alert(document.getElementById(gvdeglse').innerHTML.replaceAll(/\&nbsp\;|\s/g,''))
```

But it doesn't work, doesn't change. Can u try it and tell me, please? Maybe it is my browser.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A space is not a valid number separator. Soon using an underscore `_` will be. https://2ality.com/2020/09/ecmascript-2021.html

Comment: Do you want to count up or just replace the last Zero with One?

Comment: You could replace normal spaces with `''` as well as non-breaking spaces

Comment: just use `replaceAll( /\&nbsp\;|\s/g, '' )`

Comment: Thanks a lot It is fine replaceAll( /\&nbsp\;|\s/g, '' )

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward approach would be to convert the French string number to an integer, increment it, and then convert back:

```js
a = '20 000 000';
console.log(a);                                          // 20 000 000
a = parseInt(a.replace(/\s+/g, ''), 10) + 1;             // 20000000 => 20000001
a = a.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ' ');  // 20 000 001
console.log(a);
```

But the best practice here would be to always maintain the amount internally in your JavaScript code as an integer.  Only when you want to *display* it using French formatting, then use the latter part of my answer (or the formatting options given in the other answers).

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
var a = '20 000 000';
// Remove all spaces and parse Int
var b = parseInt(a.replace(/\s/g,''))+1;

var c = Intl.NumberFormat('fr-FR').format(b);

console.log(c); // 200 000 001
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `numeral.js` library in this way:

```js
numeral.register('locale', 'fr', {
    delimiters: {
        thousands: ' ',
        decimal: ','
    },
    abbreviations: {
        thousand: 'k',
        million: 'm',
        billion: 'b',
        trillion: 't'
    },
    ordinal : function (number) {
        return number === 1 ? 'er' : 'ème';
    },
    currency: {
        symbol: '€'
    }
});
numeral.locale('fr');
let myNumeral = numeral("20 000 000").add(1);

console.log(myNumeral.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
```